# How to make ASP.NET Core RC1 work with the GA SDK?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The previous non-GA versions of Service Fabric came with support (and template) for ASP.NET Core RC1. GA removed this support.

I have a project that depends on ASP.NET Core RC1. I would also like to update to the new SDK now.

I can get the asp.net service to run with the latest SDK without any significant changes to code. However creating a ActorProxy or ServiceProxy in the asp.net project fails with exception "The config package was not found". So my asp.net service is unable to communicate with the rest of the services in the application.

How can i fix the issue with ActorProxy and ServiceProxy on ASP.NET Core RC1 service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else discussed the same problem in the comments of Service Fabric documentation. Vaclav came up with workaround to the bug. Basically the client project requires ConfigurationPackage named "Config". Projects based on the old ASP.NET Core template didn't have the ConfigurationPackage.

For details of implementing the workaround, see:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/#comment-2601127160

Comment: This linked comment appears to be deleted